# Is there a way to make an IronPython script that takes the data in a filtered column, and sends it to another page?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have this situation within my dashboard, where I can choose parameters to filter a table with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzv7l.png)

And I need to export this data to a JSON file, using a button. This button should read the data on my table and write it down to a JSON file for sharing.

So far, what I have been able to make is not much:

```
from System.IO import File
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers

writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.StdfDataWriter)

table = Document.Data.Tables['']

filtered = Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()

stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Users\user\Desktop\TIBCO\Test_JSON.json")

names =[]
for col in table.Columns:
    names.append(col.Name)
writer.Write(stream, table, filtered, names)
stream.Close()
```

The problem with this code above is that it does not export out what I have marked, but all of the data in the table.

Comment: can you elaborate on what is missing?

Comment: Hi Gaia, well I am actually not even sure that this code is working as when I try to run it, I get errors. The idea is that this script will be inserted in a button, that will then export the relevant data from a table, but I mainly need help with the script itself since I am not proficient with IronPython

Comment: if all you need is to display filtered data in a different page, would it not be much simpler if you set a table plot in the target page which is limited by filtering? Unless I am missing some of the requirements. There is no need to export data to different pages, all pages can read and display the same data.

Comment: My bad, I confused this with another task I had to do. I have edited the question, I just need to export selected data to a JSON, not another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only problem is that it does not export marked items, this minor modification should work.
You were exporting filtered items.

```
from System.IO import File
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers

writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.StdfDataWriter)

table = Document.Data.Tables['xxx']

selection='marking'
if selection=='filter':
    selected = Document.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()
else:
    selected = Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference.GetSelection(table).AsIndexSet()

#print('n. selected',len(list(selected.GetEnumerator())))

stream = File.OpenWrite("C:\Temp\Test_JSON_"+selection+".json")

names =[]
for col in table.Columns:
    names.append(col.Name)
writer.Write(stream, table, selected, names)
stream.Close()
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I was wondering if it could be possible to, for example, extract only specific columns of the table I am trying to extract data from in the script?

Comment: how would you send these columns to the script?

Comment: I'll make another post or this risks getting confusing, if you want to please take a look at it